# Copy alt attribute of image to <p> text (and overwrite it) in jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The title says it all !  I've been struggling with this code for a while and can't figure out the problem

```
<div id="slider">
            <ul>
                <!--          -->
                <li><a target="_blank" href="ANOUK-2014-De-l'orient-a-partout-20x20.jpg"><img src="ANOUK-2014-De-l'orient-a-partout-20x20.jpg" alt="123 chf"/></a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="artSpecs">
                        <table>
                            <tr><td><p>Titre :</p></td><td><p>De l'orient à partout</p></td></tr> <!-- Titre -->
                            <tr><td><p>Medium :</p></td><td><p>Peinture</p></td></tr> <!-- Medium -->
                            <tr><td><p>Dimensions :</p></td><td><p>20 x 20 cm</p></td></tr> <!-- Dimensions -->
                            <tr><td><p>Année :</p></td><td><p>2014</p></td></tr> <!-- Année -->
                            <tr><td><p>Artiste :</p></td><td><p>Anouk</p></td></tr> <!-- Artiste -->
                            <tr><td><p>Prix :</p></td><td><p>000 CHF.</p></td></tr> <!-- Prix -->
                        </table>
                    </div>  
                </li>
                <!--          -->


                <!--          -->
                <li><a target="_blank" href="ANOUK-2014-Tout-en-beaute-20x20.jpg"><img src="ANOUK-2014-Tout-en-beaute-20x20.jpg" alt="456 chf"/></a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="artSpecs">
                        <table>
                            <tr><td><p>Titre :</p></td><td><p>Tout en beauté</p></td></tr> <!-- Titre -->
                            <tr><td><p>Medium :</p></td><td><p>Peinture</p></td></tr> <!-- Medium -->
                            <tr><td><p>Dimensions :</p></td><td><p>20 x 20 cm</p></td></tr> <!-- Dimensions -->
                            <tr><td><p>Année :</p></td><td><p>2014</p></td></tr> <!-- Année -->
                            <tr><td><p>Artiste :</p></td><td><p>Anouk</p></td></tr> <!-- Artiste -->
                            <tr><td><p>Prix :</p></td><td><p>000 CHF.</p></td></tr> <!-- Prix -->
                        </table>
                    </div>  
                </li>
                <!--          -->


                <!--          -->
                <li><a target="_blank" href="ANOUK-Ecriture-musicale-50x50-tech.mixte-sur-toile.jpg"><img src="ANOUK-Ecriture-musicale-50x50-tech.mixte-sur-toile.jpg" alt="123 chf"/></a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="artSpecs">
                        <table>
                            <tr><td><p>Titre :</p></td><td><p>Ecriture musicale</p></td></tr> <!-- Titre -->
                            <tr><td><p>Medium :</p></td><td><p>Peinture</p></td></tr> <!-- Medium -->
                            <tr><td><p>Dimensions :</p></td><td><p>50 x 50 cm</p></td></tr> <!-- Dimensions -->
                            <tr><td><p>Année :</p></td><td><p>2014</p></td></tr> <!-- Année -->
                            <tr><td><p>Artiste :</p></td><td><p>Anouk</p></td></tr> <!-- Artiste -->
                            <tr><td><p>Prix :</p></td><td><p>000 CHF.</p></td></tr> <!-- Prix -->
                        </table>
                    </div>  
                </li>
                <!--          -->


                <!--          -->
                <li><a target="_blank" href="ANOUK-Note-de-musique-40x40-tech.mixte-sur-toile.jpg"><img src="ANOUK-Note-de-musique-40x40-tech.mixte-sur-toile.jpg"/></a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="artSpecs">
                        <table>
                            <tr><td><p>Titre :</p></td><td><p>Note de Musique</p></td></tr> <!-- Titre -->
                            <tr><td><p>Medium :</p></td><td><p>Peinture</p></td></tr> <!-- Medium -->
                            <tr><td><p>Dimensions :</p></td><td><p>40 x 40 cm</p></td></tr> <!-- Dimensions -->
                            <tr><td><p>Année :</p></td><td><p>2014</p></td></tr> <!-- Année -->
                            <tr><td><p>Artiste :</p></td><td><p>Anouk</p></td></tr> <!-- Artiste -->
                            <tr><td><p>Prix :</p></td><td><p>000 CHF.</p></td></tr> <!-- Prix -->
                        </table>
                    </div>  
                </li>
                <!--          -->


                <!--          -->
                <li><a target="_blank" href="ANOUK-2014-Balade-ame-corps-80x60.jpg"><img src="ANOUK-2014-Balade-ame-corps-80x60.jpg"/></a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="artSpecs">
                        <table>
                            <tr><td><p>Titre :</p></td><td><p>Balade âme et corps</p></td></tr> <!-- Titre -->
                            <tr><td><p>Medium :</p></td><td><p>Peinture</p></td></tr> <!-- Medium -->
                            <tr><td><p>Dimensions :</p></td><td><p>80 x 60 cm</p></td></tr> <!-- Dimensions -->
                            <tr><td><p>Année :</p></td><td><p>2014</p></td></tr> <!-- Année -->
                            <tr><td><p>Artiste :</p></td><td><p>Anouk</p></td></tr> <!-- Artiste -->
                            <tr><td><p>Prix :</p></td><td><p>000 CHF.</p></td></tr> <!-- Prix -->
                        </table>
                    </div>  
                </li>
                <!--          -->
```

and the problematic jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var count = $("#slider ul").children("li").length;
for (i = 1; i < count; i = i+2) {
    alert(i);
    $("#slider ul li:nth-of-type(i+1) tr:nth-last-of-type(1) td:nth-last-of-type(1) p").text($("#slider ul li:nth-of-type(i) img").attr("alt"));}
```

});

Here is the jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/xcbnE/38/

(I put an alert() in the loop just to see if it works, and it actually only pops up once ! Which proves there's a problem, but where ??

By the way, if the script works, you should see the price  ("Prix")  of the first table in the result panel of JsFiddle change from 000 CHF. to 123 chf

Where is the problem?  I just can't figure it out.

Thanks for an answer :)

EDIT :

Okey now I REALLY need to do it this way :

http://goo.gl/ozO6PT

WHY won't it work this time ?

Please kind people I NEED an answer fast as I am approaching my deadline very soon!!

EDIT EDIT ::

Alright, I solved my problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is not well formed.
Check this update, basically well formed the string: http://goo.gl/oUZK8T